# Azure DevOps: How to publish two code coverage reports for different tests (.net core, Jest)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is my first time using Azure pipeline and I have only been exposed to C#. Our project has two tests: .net core and Jest for JS. I cannot publish the results of both at the same time.It can work normally if used alone.

$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestResults/*.trx: The directory where the test results of .net core are located
$(webProjectPath)/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml: The directory where the test results of Jest are located

[image]

[image]

Only result for .net core(This screenshot has the same result as if I only added the VSTest@2 task.)
[image]

I don't know what I missed.

Since only one test result is supported, I tried use ReportGenerator to generate the report merging, but it failed.

I hope that the results of the two tests can be merged normally and published successfully.